# How to calculate how many weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am on SQL Server and I have a table containing values like this:

```
Date        |  Key
2017-06-01  |  X
2017-06-15  |  Y
2017-06-01  |  X
2017-06-05  |  X
2017-05-23  |  Z
2017-06-05  |  Z
2017-04-10  |  Z
2017-04-10  |  Y
```

and what I need returned by the query is the number of weeks contained by each key with the starting date being: `2017-03-27`

So given our earlier example, the expected output would be:

```
X  |  2
Y  |  2
Z  |  3
```

This is because even though 01/06 and 05/06 (the two dates contained by X) are only 5 days apart they are on two different weeks (weeks being Monday to Sunday) when counting from 27/03. The number of entries related to a specific key doesn't matter, only the number of weeks dates related to that key fit into.

Comment: Weeks according to who? ISO's Monday to Sunday, or US' Sunday to Saturday etc.

Comment: Sorry, weeks are monday to sunday.

Comment: Is the week (Mon to Sunday) fixed or can change?

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: And if you have another row with `date`=`2018-01-01` and `key`=`X`, would that add just 1 to your total for `X` or would it include the total number of weeks between `2017-06-05` and `2018-01-01`?  And is `date` a date datatype or is it a varchar()?

Comment: @TabAlleman I'm not sure this is a duplicate. Unless I'm reading wrong, OP's not calculating the number of weeks between the dates but the number of times a `key` occurs in a range based on the week that it's in. So `2017-01-01` and `2018-01-01` wouldn't be 52, but just 2. But my interpretation may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT [Key], COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(WEEK,[Date])) Cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY [Key]
```

If your data spans multiple years, you could try this:

```
with cte as(
SELECT DISTINCT [Key], DATEPART(WEEK,[Date]) Wk, DATEPART(YEAR,[Date]) Yr
FROM yourTable
)
SELECT [Key], COUNT(*) Cnt
FROM cte
GROUP BY [Key]
```

Comment: Yup, this is perfect. I feel silly for not thinking of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the days after 2017-03-27 and divide by 7:

```
select t.*, ( datediff(day, '2017-03-27', date) / 7 ) as num_weeks
from t;
```

Then you can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select key, count(distinct datediff(day, '2017-03-27', date) / 7 ) as num_weeks
from t
group by key;
```

Comment: Did you read the last paragraph in the question?   Wouldn't this do the opposite?

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . I think a more precise statement is that I didn't understand its relevance to the question being asked.  I think I figured it out and modified the answer.

Comment: This is a pretty clean and very portable answer. One thing to keep in mind is that the input date (`2017-03-27`) will impact the definition of a week. So since `27 Mar 2017` is a Monday, the week will start on a Monday and count that way. But if the input date was `2017-03-28`, then the week count would start on Tuesday. That can be very flexible, but will require you to know what day of the week your input date is. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4d565748f82e3817d5afa6060231c905

Comment: @Shawn . . . That the input date defines the definition of week is *exactly* what I thought the OP was asking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm always impressed with how you can make analytics so simple-looking and how quickly you come to the solution. I was thinking along my standard line of this being another good case for a Calendar Table. But that may be overkill here, and your method is _much_ easier. :-) The only thing I would check on it is how it scales to lots of records.